# check if this hours is available

Tags: java, date

I have a question.
I am new and I need help with this.
I have an array of lessons in training room, each lesson has date, and time for ex.
KICKBOXING Lesson in on 01/05/2016 from 16:00 to 18:00.

Now i am making a method, that adds a lesson to this array.
but, I have to make sure, while adding a new lesson, that in this lesson's Date and time, I need to make sure that the room is not busy.
I mean that there is no other lesson in has the same date and time.
how should i check that?

I though about a way like this:
but did not work

```
    public boolean checkDate(Date date)
{
    for (int i = 0;i<Lesson.length;i++)
    if(Lesson[i].getStartDate().getHours() == date.getHours() && Lesson[i].getStartDate().getMinutes() == date.getMinutes())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean addLessons(Lesson les)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Lesson.length; i++)
    if(les.getRoom().getRoomType() != E_Rooms.GYM && Lesson[i] != null && checkDate(les.getStartDate())== false)    
    {
        for(int a = 0; i<Lesson.length;i++)
             if(Lesson[i]==null)
             {
                 Lesson[a] = les;
                 return true;
             }
    }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work

```
public boolean checkDate(Date beginDate, Date endDate){
    for (int i = 0;i<Lesson.length;i++)
        if(Lesson[i].getBeginDate() < endDate || Lesson[i].getEndDate() > beginDate){
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (int i = 0;i<Lesson.length;i++)
 if(Lesson[i].getBeginDate() == beginDate || Lesson[i].getEndDate() == endDate){ 
   return false; //means there's a class in this date/time }
 else
     return true; // there's no class in this time. do something..
```

Comment: It is not correct. For example you have lesson 16-18. You want to add lesson 16-17.

Comment: OP said wants to be sure the room is not busy. read him question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The troublesome legacy date-time classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

### `Interval`

Those classes are further extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. That project’s classes include the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class that may be of use to you. An `Interval` represents a span of time between a pair of `Instant` objects. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). The `Interval` class has handy methods for comparing: abuts, contains, overlaps, encloses.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of( LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 2 ) , LocalTime.of( 16 , 0 , 0 ) , zoneId );
Instant start1 = zdt1.toInstant();
Instant stop1 = zdt1.plusHours( 2 ).toInstant(); // 18:00:00.0 = ( 16:00:00.0 + 2 hours ).
Interval reservation1 = Interval.of( start1 , stop1 );
```

A [look to the class doc](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html#of-java.time.Instant-java.time.Duration-) shows that you can create an `Interval` with use of a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). This might be handy for you.

```
Duration duration = Duration.of( 2 , ChronoUnit.HOURS );
Interval reservation = Interval( zdt.toInstant() , duration );
```

You could collect instances of `Interval` objects, each representing a reservation. Additional `Interval` objects can be compared to the already-collected objects to see if they overlap.

```
boolean res1OverlapsRes2 = reservation1.overlaps( reservation2 );
```

If you are certain reservations do not roll over midnight, you might create a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) as the Key and a collection of that date’s `Interval` objects collection as the Value. For any [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), call [`toLocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate--) to get a `LocalDate` object to do lookup in the Map. With that date’s collection of Intervals, loop to see if the `Interval` being added overlaps with any of the pre-existing `Interval` objects.

The java.time and ThreeTen-Extra classes use the Half-Open approach where a span of time is defined with the beginning being *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Search for "half-open" to learn more.